# How to bin data from multiple columns?

Tags: pandas, bin

I have the following df

```
|   1   |   2   |   3   |
-------------------------
  0.11     0.25    0.74
  0.32     0.93    0.26
  0.44     0.28    0.76
  0.15     0.29    0.79
```

etc.

I'm using bins:

```
bins = [0,.1,.2,.3,.4,.5,.6,.7,.8,.9,1]
```

I created 3 bin columns and ran a value_counts() on them. So now I know how many values are in each bin for each of these 3 columns. But I'm having trouble plotting this into a barplot. Looking for a triple bar graph

```
df['Bin1'] = pd.cut(df['1'], bins)
df['Bin2'] = pd.cut(df['2'], bins)
df['Bin3'] = pd.cut(df['3'], bins)
Bin1_count = df['Bin1'].value_counts().values
Bin2_count = df['Bin2'].value_counts().values
Bin3_count = df['Bin3'].value_counts().values
x_axis = df['Bin1'].value_counts().index

sns.barplot(x = x_axis, y = [Bin1_count,Bin2_count,Bin3_count])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can using `melt` first , then using `pd.crosstab`, and try look at `plot` from [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)

```
meltdf=df.melt()
meltdf.value=pd.cut(meltdf.value,bins)
pd.crosstab(meltdf.variable,meltdf.value).plot(kind='bar')
```

Comment: I also have other columns in the df of other types so I'm getting a "'<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'" error

Comment: @user10939484 do `meltdf=df[['1','2','3']].melt()`

Comment: Nevermind, just made a separate dataframe of columns I needed. Thanks